# Is recall study more effective than recognition study for learning vocabulary?

Tags: learning-methods, reference-request

According to Tim Ferris,

> If you train for recall, you get recognition automatically; if you train for recognition, recall is terrible, or as slow as molasses. (See [The Time Ferris Show, 19 June 2014](http://fourhourworkweek.com/2014/06/19/drawing-a-penny/)).

Even though it sounds intuitively plausible, is there actually any **research to back up the statement that learning vocabulary for [recall](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recall_%28memory%29) gives you recognition "for free"**?

The question is relevant to the creation of **flashcards** (on paper or in an SRS): is creating flashcards for recall sufficient, or do you also need flashcards for recognition?

---

Since this questions asks for studies to support the answers, see the [Resources for Researching Language Learning Questions](https://languagelearning.meta.stackexchange.com/q/440/800).

Comment: It's not free because learning for recall is harder than recognition x2 or whatever.

Comment: @SAH I know what you mean, but "for free" here means that you don't need to *add* recognition study when you're already doing recall study.

Comment: For people (like me) who are not 100% sure how recall vs recognition works, and what is the difference: interesting article about [Memory Recognition and Recall in User Interfaces](https://www.nngroup.com/articles/recognition-and-recall/)

Answer (score 1):

> What is more, Glover’s (1989) research suggests that **recall is more effective in learning than recognition**, and that
>   multiple-choice in web-based learning tends to reinforce recognition, not recall. According to constructivist
>   assumption stressing the active construction of knowledge and situational activities (see Han, 1990), **recall is a much
>   more important intellectual activity than recognition because recall makes retrieving schemata an easier process for
>   the learner. This coincides with the context where students construct their knowledge through the representation of
>   specific knowledge internally and the interpretation of personal experiences. In the same context, recall plays a
>   greater role in transferring knowledge than recognition, because recognition is a process of simply retrieving what
>   the learner has obtained previously or what the learner has memorized** (Han, 1990).
>
> Viewed from the fact that recall and recognition are two different
>   cognitive processes and that recall is closely related to the transfer
>   of knowledge, it is unfavorable to adopt a multiple response mode that
>   requires recognition in web-based learning. Graff (2003) suggests that
>   introducing design principles that incorporate the learners’ cognitive
>   style (i.e., holistic and analytic) with content might be instrumental
>   in developing an effective instructional program. Thus, what is needed
>   at this time is to test response modes that support active
>   intellectual recall and the transfer of knowledge matching to the
>   context. More specifically, it is the explicit response presented at
>   the time when feedback is given that requires greater concern.

From "[Improving Recall and Transfer Skills Through Vocabulary Building in WebBased
Second Language Learning: An Examination by Item and Feedback
Type](http://www.ifets.info/journals/11_4/12.pdf)" by Yun et al, *Educational Technology & Society*, 11.4 (2008), 158–172.

Comment: Would you be willing to elaborate on how this quote answers the question, preferably in your own words?

Comment: @Hatchet I added emphasis.

Comment: Could you add the full reference to the paper (authors, journal, year)? And possibly the full references for the papers cited in the quoted excerpt?