# Is it more efficient to make flashcards for L3 in L2 and L1?

Tags: reference-request, flash-cards, anki, japanese

I'm currently learning Japanese as my L3, using flashcards (Anki) for kanji vocabulary.

My L1 is Portuguese and L2 is English (fluent). Is it more efficient to make flashcards for L3 in L2 and L1? Would it make me associate information faster because of the information diversity?

Comment: Not sure, but this question might be close enough to be considered a duplicate of https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/q/2351/85 However, this question deals with efficiency while the other asks about confusion.

Comment: @Hatchet I think this question is different enough not to be considered a duplicate.

Comment: Are you looking for scientific studies to support this?

Comment: @fi12 I wouldn't put too much hope in finding studies that compare the effectiveness of L1 flash cards versus L1+L2 flash cards for learning an L3.

Comment: @fi12, no not necessarily, but it would be apreciated

Comment: I think the answer to this question depends on what you mean by "efficiency." Is your goal to learn your L3 as easily and quickly as possible? Or is your goal to reduce interference with your L2?  Since your L3 and L2 are very different, you're not likely to experience a lot of interference, but some amount is inevitable, so it's still worth clarifying. Further, what are you trying to learn in your L3? (Reading, writing, speaking, comprehension, all of the above?)

Comment: In any case, you should consider using only your L3 on your flashcards, at least once you've achieved a minimal reading comprehension level in your L3. I talk about this more [here](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/a/2363/13), but the basic concept is: Flashcards from L1:L2 teach you to _translate_, which is usually not what you want. So you're usually better off with flashcards entirely in your target language.

Comment: I've started doing that and seems like it's doing a good job at making me _understand_ not translate. thanks.

Comment: I also learn Japanese. I use French or English resources simply based on what exists. No French book goes beyond 600 kanji, so I (have to) use an English one. I expect the situation is similar for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In terms of efficiency, it is likely better to make the flashcards in conjunction with your L1. In terms of effectiveness of retaining your non-native languages, however, then it would be better to make the flashcards in conjunction with your L2. This technique is called **laddering**.

[Here](http://www.alljapaneseallthetime.com/blog/how-to-learn-multiple-languages-without-getting-confused-the-laddering-method/) is one of the most popular (non-scientific) laddering articles, and he describes the technique as a way to help avoid confusion among several languages and also an effective technique to learn, and maintain, multiple languages.